# Connection from local Wordpress with local external SQL Server database

Tags: php, sql-server, database, wordpress, localhost

I have set up a local Wordpress installation on my macbook. Know I want to display data from an existing external local database (SQL Server) with queries. How can I solve this problem? I have access to the database with Azure Data Studio

I created my own theme (blank site) and activated it, know I want a connection:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);


define ( 'MYSQL_HOST',      'localhost' );
define ( 'MYSQL_BENUTZER',  'user' );
define ( 'MYSQL_KENNWORT',  '' );
define ( 'MYSQL_DATENBANK', '' );

$db_link = mysqli_connect (MYSQL_HOST, 
                           MYSQL_BENUTZER, 
                           MYSQL_KENNWORT, 
                           MYSQL_DATENBANK);

if ( $db_link )
{
    echo 'Verbindung erfolgreich: ';
    print_r( $db_link);
}
else
{
    die('keine Verbindung möglich: ' . mysqli_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: WordPress doesn't support SQL server out of the box; so getting past that is your first major problem. If you need to use SQL Server with WordPress you either need to heavily modify the application, or download a 3rd party version that does.

Comment: What is a better solution than WordPress to get my problem solved? 
In General i need to show with queries Data on a site.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't for tool recommendations i am afraid.

Comment: That isn't sql-server syntax, it's mysql.

Comment: I have a local mysql database in docker container

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress does not natively support MS SQL Server. However, a team of SQL Server developers created and maintain [Project Nami](https://projectnami.org) as a fork of the platform that supports SQL Server and Azure.

The most recent version of Project Nami uses Wordpress 5.5.1 (current version). I suggest reviewing the Project Nami's [plugin compatibility](https://projectnami.org/plugin-compatibility/) page to check for unsupported plugins.

The source code of the project is available at [Project Nami's GitHub](https://github.com/ProjectNami/projectnami) repository.

Comment: Thanks for your inforation.
Is there a possibility to show datas from a local ms sql server in a local html site oder local php site?

Comment: Yes. Use `localhost` as the database host during the installation. The config.php file created from the installation is very similar to the MySQL connection shown in your question.